# What is the best way of syncing data to a Realm backend on a multiple page iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an application with a login screen and then two table views in a tab bar controller once the user has logged in. In each table view, I have data which I would like to sync to my Realm Database.

The setup of my Realm database is heavily based on the following tutorial: https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/

The code for user authentication is as below

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: userCredentials, server: (url! as URL)) { user, error in
    guard user != nil else {
        print("Error")
        self.logInMessage.text = "Invalid login details, please try again"
        self.logInMessage.shake()
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logInSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

In each of my tableviews I aim to have the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Open Realm
    let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
        syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://127.0.0.1:9080/~/realmtasks")!)
    )
    self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
}
```

However, note that I need a user to for the configuration. Should I pass this from the login screen, or is this overkill? Thanks in advance

Comment: a simple thing you could do is to create a `UserManager` singleton, having a `currentUser` property. when get your user at login, you just assign the user to `currentUser`, and than you have access to it in your whole application, something like `UserManager.shared.currentUser`.

Comment: That's a good idea, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks

Comment: It's not a good idea at all, you can set a default configuration with `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config` then you can use `let realm = try! Realm()` normally. without having to create SyncConfiguration each time, also singleton does not take thread-localness into account therefore you should actually have a singleton that allows you to query what you need from the Realm instance that you provide as method argument

Comment: Ahh I see, that worked perfectly- thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up your Realm's default configuration when your app launches (even before you authenticate a user). This could go in your AppDelegate or a similar "startup" file.

```
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
    syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://127.0.0.1:9080/~/realmtasks")!)
)

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration
```

Then in the first view that loads, you take care of user authentication (this will probably require some UI so your user can log in unless you use iCloud authentication with Realm which can happen behind-the-scenes).

Once you have authenticated a user, you can access their `SyncUser` object anytime:

```
//Log out the user (for example)
SyncUser.current?.logOut()
```

Good luck! :)